# How do I choose a folder to store files from Docker?

Tags: docker, windows-10

I've been working on this for hours, but I've mainly found answers relating to Linux.

I'm running Docker in Windows 10, and I'm trying to install some distros from [Linuxserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/headphones/)

I can do a basic setup (following [a guide](https://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-jackett-using-docker/) that install Jackett a similar way)

```
docker create --name=jackett \
--restart=always \
-v /home/docker/jackett/config:/config \
-v /home/docker/jackett/downloads:/downloads \
-e PGID=1001 -e PUID=1001 \
-e TZ=Europe/London \
-p 9117:9117 \
linuxserver/jackett
```

But, I don't understand how to select one of the shared drives I setup, and I have no idea where `/home/...` is on my hard drive.

How would I set this up to save config and downloads in say:

```
H:\Documents\Configs
```

Answer (score 0):

docker volume definitions are in pairs

> -v left_side:right_side

where full path of left side is a directory local to the machine where you are executing your docker command from ... your laptop or server ... whereas the right_side is same directory as viewed from inside the freshly launched container ... that is you are mounting a local dir to your container so it can read and write to persist changes even after the container is killed off

For example I want to make visable to my app the dir on my laptop of

```
/some/full/path/local/dir
```

and the app will see this as path

```
/whatever/dir
```

so syntax would look like this

```
docker  ... skip settings ...  -v /some/full/path/local/dir:/whatever/dir
```

My guess is if your host machine is MS Windows then use Windows \ separators rather than linux / separators

```
docker  ... skip settings ...  -v c:\some\full\path\local\dir:/whatever/dir
```

so this would be linux host syntax

```
docker create --name=jackett \
--restart=always \
-v /some/config/dir:/config \
-v /some/config/dir:/downloads \
-e PGID=1001 -e PUID=1001 \
-e TZ=Europe/London \
-p 9117:9117 \
linuxserver/jackett
```

whereas this is MS Windows syntax using \ instead of / as seperator

```
docker create --name=jackett \
--restart=always \
-v H:\\Documents\\Configs:/config \
-v H:\\Documents\\Configs:/downloads \
-e PGID=1001 -e PUID=1001 \
-e TZ=Europe/London \
-p 9117:9117 \
linuxserver/jackett
```

UPDATE - notice the double \ which might work on Windows since a single \ just means do an escape on following character ... Also leave as is the last line of above `linuxserver/jackett`  as that is not a path its the docker image name

on ubuntu I just ran below just fine

```
docker create --name=jackett_stens  \
--restart=always \
-v /home/khufu/src/config:/config \
-v /home/khufu/src/config:/downloads \
-e PGID=1001 -e PUID=1001 \
-e TZ=Europe/London \
-p 9117:9117 \
linuxserver/jackett
```

above output is

```
khufu@jill ~ $ docker create --name=jackett_stens  \
> --restart=always \
> -v /home/khufu/src/config:/config \
> -v /home/khufu/src/config:/downloads \
> -e PGID=1001 -e PUID=1001 \
> -e TZ=Europe/London \
> -p 9117:9117 \
> linuxserver/jackett
Unable to find image 'linuxserver/jackett:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from linuxserver/jackett
f2233041f557: Already exists 
53bd17864f23: Pull complete 
02efc09c990b: Pull complete 
14b057e5c85e: Pull complete 
7e03e93fc218: Pull complete 
9825bf39efb1: Pull complete 
0a74d4d4cac0: Pull complete 
34451e5c900f: Pull complete 
5453d859f994: Pull complete 
d9976cfaf0ba: Pull complete 
09ccdb48553d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:b624cbc75efb40d7dab9a2095653988632a4773ad86e0f5ee2edd877e4178678
Status: Downloaded newer image for linuxserver/jackett:latest
dddfae776bfc32c3a55de1ddc08c04e2574ecb3c950ba9bb88f477e3e240121e
```

OK so above worked then I launched the image using

```
docker start  jackett_stens
```

and confirmed it is running by issuing

```
docker ps
```

Comment: That causes an error because of the backslashes (invalid reference format), and if I forward slash it says "repository name must be lowercase"

Comment: @StackJohan I updated my syntax ... does it work now ?

Comment: Afraid not - `docker : invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
At line:1 char:1
+ docker create  --name=jackett -v H:\\Documents\\Configs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (invalid referen...st be lowercase:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError`

Comment: OK just remove mention of --name=jackett   as  the last line defines the repository along with image name

Comment: Hmm...okay, I'll try that, but I just did an experiment and found that h:\\ works, but I don't know how to test it. Is there a command to write a test.txt file?

Comment: I just noticed you are using docker create ... however if you simply want to launch a new container using their image just use docker run  instead of docker create  ... in above command ... typical sequence is docker build --tag myimagename .  where you issue that cmd in dir which has your Dockerfile ... then image gets created ... then launch using docker run -ti myimagename

Comment: Hmm, the run command produced some interesting new output if I went back to using the directories from the tutorial, but changing `-name=jackett` and using backslashes produced the same errors

Comment: Make certain you have NO spaces in any directory name nor file name especially the ones you supply to your -v for volumes ... I do not have a Windows machine to confirm on

Comment: *sigh* - and I noticed I have another brother that is probably unrelated, but - I ran Headphones the same way as I've been trying Jackett and can't connect to my nzbget. - as for the spaces, isn't there a way to do escapes?